# Meaning of "Cut my legs out from under me"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-meaning

I would like to know the exact meaning of this phrase "**cut my legs out from under me**".

I've been searching for it everywhere, but until now I've only come across the definition of "cut the ground from under somebody's feet". And I know it is not the same. Though, I've heard on some TV shows people saying "cut my legs out from under me".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Merriam Webster's definition for [have one's legs/feet/knees cut out from under (one)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20one%27s%20legs/feet/knees%20cut%20out%20from%20under%20(one)) is as follows:

> be knocked down by something that hits one's legs very hard
>
> - When I learned that I was seriously ill, I felt as if my feet were cut out from under me.
>
> often used figuratively.
>
> - When the program lost the grant its financial legs had been cut out from under it.

According to MW's popularity index they list it as " Bottom 10% of words"

I can't say I've heard it before. While searching online I saw an equivalent French term "couper l'herbe sous le pied", and also saw more example sentences.

Two of the example sentences quoted below are of Canadian origin.

> - Organized crime has emerged as the number one threat to Canada's overall security, yet the government has cut the legs out from under Canada's security committee
> - "Having a national formulary as a defining component of a national pharmacare program," said Brian Ferguson, "would cut the legs out from under the provinces to make decisions about how they ration across different parts of their programs."
>   ([sources for this quote](https://www.google.pt/search?ei=oAyQW5rWJsaesgGE84iQDA&q=Having%20a%20national%20formulary%20as%20a%20defining%20component%20of%20a%20national%20pharmacare%20program&oq=Having%20a%20national%20formulary%20as%20a%20defining%20component%20of%20a%20national%20pharmacare%20program&gs_l=psy-ab.3...194551.214320.0.215693.2.2.0.0.0.0.83.83.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.OLeusFD5zb8))

Perhaps it's an expression that has transitioned from French Canadians to English Canadians?

Thinking about this further, I know an expression "to have your legs **kicked** out from under you" which would basically hold the same meaning as MW's definition above.

Comment: As a Canadian, I've heard the phrase often. (Although I don't know if it came from French Canada.) I'd also say it's an idiom here.

Comment: What a gruesome expression. :) New to me too.

Comment: I’ve heard it, in BrE. Think of a fouling soccer player aiming for the legs of his opponent instead of aiming for the ball.

Comment: I've heard it; maybe relevant that I'm from a border state (Michigan)? Also versions using *knock* instead of cut.

Answer (score 0):

My Dad used to use the term in a manner with less outward accusation (not blaming another) of “my legs went out from under me”, I think he meant it in the sense of being utterly flabbergasted or staggered by what someone says.